# How to remove local untracked files from the current Git branch using Windows Command prompt

Tags: git, github, git-status

:git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Untracked files:
(use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
"\357\200\233\357\200\233\357\200\233\357\200\233\357\200\233\357\200\233\357
\200\233\357\200\233\357\200\233\357\200\233\357\200\233\357\200\233\357\200\233\357
200\272"

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

:

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**> How to remove local untracked files from the current Git branch using Windows Command prompt**

`:git status`

On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Untracked files:
(use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
"\357\200\233\357\200\233\357\200\233\357\200\233\357\200\233\357\200\233\357
\200\233\357\200\233\357\200\233\357\200\233\357\200\233\357\200\233\357\200\233\357
200\272"

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

---

- `SOLUTION`

  `:git clean -fd`

  Removing "\357\200\233\357\200\233\357\200\233\357\200\233\357\200\233\357\200\233\35
  7\200\233\357\200\233\357\200\233\357\200\233\357\200\233\357\200\233\357\200\233\357
  \200\272"

  `:git status`

  On branch main
  Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.
  nothing to commit, working tree clean

: